# How do I check if a module is being used by another?

Tags: drush, files

I'm using a multi-site setup with Drupal 7.14 core, and I want to disable some modules within my sites/all/modules shared folder. One of them in particular is the File_Entity module.

Is there a way (drush, programmatically, bash script, etc) to check if another module (e.g. Views, custom CCK) is using it? `drush pml | grep File Entity` only let me see what is enabled or disabled, not if it is currently in use, or safe to remove.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
drush pm-info mymodule|grep "Required by"
```

grep or don't grep is up to you ;)

Beware this does not list fields that require the module. This implies to views that use fields too.

```
fields: admin/reports/fields

views: admin/reports/fields/views-fields
```

those will list fields only, so if you have special pagers, formatters or something else that come from a module you will still have to search for them.

Comment: Yes, there can be dependencies in configuration as well as in code. For example if you create a view using a handler supplied by a module, then uninstall that module the view will break. Can be hard to track all these down.

Comment: As an example of a real stinker, suppose a module includes a template preprocess function that rearranges the content of certain variables. Your theme might depend on this having been done, but try tracking that down without code inspection!

Comment: hopefully those are listed as dependencies in the .info file for the actual module or theme (thats what that notice is for) if not you have a problem - but that mess is caused by bad style then.

Comment: Sure, that's what a developer /should/ do, but how many do when writing a custom theme for a single site? Considering how many times I've found SQL queries in template.php functions, that's a relatively minor offence :)

Comment: So, how can I achive similar result with Drush 9 ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no `drush pm-info` command in Drush 9.3, it was replaced `pm:list`.

(https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/3487, https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/5557)

But now there is no `Required by` field in a field list
(see FIELDS section in `drush pm:list --help`)

Current workaround is just open `/admin/modules` page and look for `Required by`,
or use some php code if you have access to the drush.

```
drush ev '$module = "views"; $modules = _system_rebuild_module_data(); \Drupal::moduleHandler()->buildModuleDependencies($modules); var_dump($modules[$module]->required_by);'
```

**UPD**: Drupal 9 version:

```
# Dependencies of the module
drush ev '$module = "views"; $modules = \Drupal::service("extension.list.module")->getList(); echo implode(array_keys($modules[$module]->requires),", ");'
# Dependencies to the module
drush ev '$module = "views"; $modules = \Drupal::service("extension.list.module")->getList(); echo implode(array_keys($modules[$module]->required_by),", ");'
```

**NOTE**: be worried with php code, may cause performance issues.

Comment: This worked well, but I tweaked it a little to clean up the output. Editing above.

Comment: Thank you @froboy! I would add also `."\n"` into echo statements.